# Setting a different background colour behind the content of a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**THE AIM**

I would like that when the dropdown is opened (*toggle-content* is active) the background, apart from the header, would have a different colour and the user wouldn't be able to scroll through the background content until the dropdown is closed.

**THE PROBLEM AND THE ATTEMPT**

I've managed to prevent the user from scrolling by using
`$('body').toggleClass('hidden');`.
However, I am not being able to set a different colour in the background. For this, I've tried placing an empty div with class *backdrop* and style it to set a background colour with an opacity of 0.5.

Please find my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('active');
    $('body').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.text {
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.toggle.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.toggle.active .backdrop {
  display: block !important;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-content.active {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toggle">T</div>
    <div class="toggle-content">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

Expetenda tincidunt in sed, ex partem placerat sea, porro commodo ex eam. His putant aeterno interesset at. Usu ea mundi tincidunt, omnium virtute aliquando ius ex. Ea aperiri sententiae duo. Usu nullam dolorum quaestio ei, sit vidit facilisis ea. Per ne impedit iracundia neglegentur. Consetetur neglegentur eum ut, vis animal legimus inimicus id.

His audiam deserunt in, eum ubique voluptatibus te. In reque dicta usu. Ne rebum dissentiet eam, vim omnis deseruisse id. Ullum deleniti vituperata at quo, insolens complectitur te eos, ea pri dico munere propriae. Vel ferri facilis ut, qui paulo ridens praesent ad. Possim alterum qui cu. Accusamus consulatu ius te, cu decore soleat appareat usu.

Est ei erat mucius quaeque. Ei his quas phaedrum, efficiantur mediocritatem ne sed, hinc oratio blandit ei sed. Blandit gloriatur eam et. Brute noluisse per et, verear disputando neglegentur at quo. Sea quem legere ei, unum soluta ne duo. Ludus complectitur quo te, ut vide autem homero pro.

Vis id minim dicant sensibus. Pri aliquip conclusionemque ad, ad malis evertitur torquatos his. Has ei solum harum reprimique, id illum saperet tractatos his. Ei omnis soleat antiopam quo. Ad augue inani postulant mel, mel ea qualisque forensibus.

Lorem salutandi eu mea, eam in soleat iriure assentior. Tamquam lobortis id qui. Ea sanctus democritum mei, per eu alterum electram adversarium. Ea vix probo dicta iuvaret, posse epicurei suavitate eam an, nam et vidit menandri. Ut his accusata petentium.

Meis vocent signiferumque pri et. Facilis corpora recusabo ne quo, eum ne eruditi blandit suscipiantur. Mazim sapientem sed id, sea debet commune iracundia in. Eius falli propriae te usu. In usu nonummy volumus expetenda, sint quando facilisis ei per, delectus constituto sea te.

Wisi forensibus mnesarchum in cum. Per id impetus abhorreant, his no magna definiebas, inani rationibus in quo. Ut vidisse dolores est, ut quis nominavi mel. Ad pri quod apeirian concludaturque, id timeam iudicabit rationibus pri. Erant putant luptatum ex sit, error euismod ad qui, meliore voluptatum complectitur an vix. Clita persius sed et, vix vidit consulatu complectitur ex. Per nonummy postulant assentior an, mea audiam fabellas deserunt id.

Cu nam labores lobortis definiebas, ei aliquyam salutatus persequeris quo, cum eu nemore fierent dissentiunt. Per vero dolor id, vide democritum scribentur eu vim, pri erroribus temporibus ex. Euismod molestie offendit has no. Quo te semper invidunt quaestio, per vituperatoribus sadipscing ei, partem aliquyam sensibus in cum.

Mei eu mollis albucius, ex nisl contentiones vix. Duo persius volutpat at, cu iuvaret epicuri mei. Duo posse pertinacia no, ex dolor contentiones mea. Nec omnium utamur dignissim ne. Mundi lucilius salutandi an sea, ne sea aeque iudico comprehensam. Populo delicatissimi ad pri. Ex vitae accusam vivendum pro.
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add extra div (`.overlay`) inside `.container` and apply the css with js, check the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle, .overlay').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('active');
    $('body').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('.overlay').toggleClass('active'); // <-- add this
    //$('.wrapper').toggleClass('active'); // <-- add this also
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  z-index: 30;
}

.text {
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.toggle.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.toggle.active .backdrop {
  display: block !important;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-content.active {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 200;
}
.wrapper.active{
  background: black;
  z-index: 5;
}
.overlay{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  display: none;
  opacity: .5;
  top: 0;
}
.overlay.active{
  display: block;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toggle">T</div>
    <div class="toggle-content">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

Expetenda tincidunt in sed, ex partem placerat sea, porro commodo ex eam. His putant aeterno interesset at. Usu ea mundi tincidunt, omnium virtute aliquando ius ex. Ea aperiri sententiae duo. Usu nullam dolorum quaestio ei, sit vidit facilisis ea. Per ne impedit iracundia neglegentur. Consetetur neglegentur eum ut, vis animal legimus inimicus id.

His audiam deserunt in, eum ubique voluptatibus te. In reque dicta usu. Ne rebum dissentiet eam, vim omnis deseruisse id. Ullum deleniti vituperata at quo, insolens complectitur te eos, ea pri dico munere propriae. Vel ferri facilis ut, qui paulo ridens praesent ad. Possim alterum qui cu. Accusamus consulatu ius te, cu decore soleat appareat usu.

Est ei erat mucius quaeque. Ei his quas phaedrum, efficiantur mediocritatem ne sed, hinc oratio blandit ei sed. Blandit gloriatur eam et. Brute noluisse per et, verear disputando neglegentur at quo. Sea quem legere ei, unum soluta ne duo. Ludus complectitur quo te, ut vide autem homero pro.

Vis id minim dicant sensibus. Pri aliquip conclusionemque ad, ad malis evertitur torquatos his. Has ei solum harum reprimique, id illum saperet tractatos his. Ei omnis soleat antiopam quo. Ad augue inani postulant mel, mel ea qualisque forensibus.

Lorem salutandi eu mea, eam in soleat iriure assentior. Tamquam lobortis id qui. Ea sanctus democritum mei, per eu alterum electram adversarium. Ea vix probo dicta iuvaret, posse epicurei suavitate eam an, nam et vidit menandri. Ut his accusata petentium.

Meis vocent signiferumque pri et. Facilis corpora recusabo ne quo, eum ne eruditi blandit suscipiantur. Mazim sapientem sed id, sea debet commune iracundia in. Eius falli propriae te usu. In usu nonummy volumus expetenda, sint quando facilisis ei per, delectus constituto sea te.

Wisi forensibus mnesarchum in cum. Per id impetus abhorreant, his no magna definiebas, inani rationibus in quo. Ut vidisse dolores est, ut quis nominavi mel. Ad pri quod apeirian concludaturque, id timeam iudicabit rationibus pri. Erant putant luptatum ex sit, error euismod ad qui, meliore voluptatum complectitur an vix. Clita persius sed et, vix vidit consulatu complectitur ex. Per nonummy postulant assentior an, mea audiam fabellas deserunt id.

Cu nam labores lobortis definiebas, ei aliquyam salutatus persequeris quo, cum eu nemore fierent dissentiunt. Per vero dolor id, vide democritum scribentur eu vim, pri erroribus temporibus ex. Euismod molestie offendit has no. Quo te semper invidunt quaestio, per vituperatoribus sadipscing ei, partem aliquyam sensibus in cum.

Mei eu mollis albucius, ex nisl contentiones vix. Duo persius volutpat at, cu iuvaret epicuri mei. Duo posse pertinacia no, ex dolor contentiones mea. Nec omnium utamur dignissim ne. Mundi lucilius salutandi an sea, ne sea aeque iudico comprehensam. Populo delicatissimi ad pri. Ex vitae accusam vivendum pro.
  </div>

</div>
```